# How to bitbake clean altera-image-minimal?

Tags: yocto, intel-fpga, bitbake

I am a beginner to Yocto Linux and having trouble with clean up rootfs filesystem in the build image folder using

```
bitbake -c clean altera-image-minimal altera-gsrd-image
```

I did successful with

```
bitbake -c clean virtual/kernel virtual/bootloader
```

to remove kernel and uboot generated files from "~/Build1/tmp/deploy/images", but not the filesystem. I tried with `-f` to force clean the generated filesystem but it doesn't seem like doing anything. If anyone have experienced similar issue, can you help share your solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Formatting your command lines may help those who want to help better understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If by clean up you mean remove the rootfs and what it generates then just delete the `~/Build1/tmp` folder.

The next time you compile, do not need to worry since you have files stored in `SSTATE_CACHE` and `download` to speed up the process.

bitbake -c clean will only clean the stuff in `/build/tmp/work/` folders.  This is used when you want to recompile something again.

Comment: You are correct. I deleted generated files from 
~/Build1/tmp/deploy/images 
and was able to recompile
bitbake altera-images-minimal
The different that I observe is when I execute
bitbake -c clean virtual/kernel virtual/bootloader
This command actually remove the generated files in ~Build1/tmp/deploy/images folder and clean the stuff in /Build1/tmp/work/

bitbake -c clean altera-image-minimal
This command only clean the stuff in /Build1/tmp/work/ folder and kept generated files untouch.

Thank you for your answer.